# WebService without response

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have this webservice class

```
@WebService(serviceName = "Reception", name = "PersonalName")
public class webswsdl {
    public void receptionOC(org.tempuri.SalesOrderHeader salesOrderHeader) {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

This is Ok and the webservice works well

But this have a response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ReceptionOCResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need to do the same webservice but without response.

Comment: WHY do you want to stop the response ?

Comment: What do you mean no response? Empty response?

Comment: @Yahia I want to stop the response because this is the company request, and i don't now how do this.

Comment: @Maxim is that there appears no response, nothing.

Comment: Additional to @Max you could set Response to ServiceUnavailable(503) or NoContent(204) or other status, depending on that you want, like this: Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent;

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to understanding all the bindings which take place here, and you want it fast and very straightforward, that's the way:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Just put this into your web method function.